# What is const reference of the return value?

Tags: c++

```
int func_a()
{
    int a = 1;
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{

    int a1 = func_a();
    const int& a2 = func_a();
    return 0;
}
```

`a` is destroyed when the function return, so what is the inside of `a2`?
Does `a2` copy the return value of `func_a`? (Does `a2` is better than `a1` in performance?)

---

About my last question. I tried the test below, and the result shows it is no difference in the performance.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef uint8_t Byte;
typedef std::vector<Byte> Bytes;

#define benchmark(f)\
    {auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();  \
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) \
        f;  \
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();    \
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - begin);    \
    std::cout << "Cost of code is " << elapsed .count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;}

Bytes func_a()
{
    Bytes a(10000);
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{

    benchmark({
                  const Bytes& a2 = func_a();
              })
    benchmark({
                  Bytes a1 = func_a();
              })
    return 0;
}

Cost of code is 2893 milliseconds
Cost of code is 2893 milliseconds

Cost of code is 2883 milliseconds
Cost of code is 2895 milliseconds
```

Comment: [Extending lifetime of a temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)

Comment: With guaranteed RVO in C++17 this is mostly unneeded, any more, but the linked questions explains the original purpose.

Comment: Neither `a1` or `a2` is "better", they both fill different roles. In the example you provided the practical effect is that `a1` is mutable and `a2` isn't. The example doesn't actually illustrate extending the lifetime of a temporary because a function can always return it's own type. (so as you have found, reference or not, you can assign the return of `func_a` without problems) The intent of the constant reference initialization is lifetime extension, it just isn't exactly what your example shows.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc I add the more test code to see the performance.